# While loop to build an array instead of looping 100+ times

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'office',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
]);

$offices = [];
if (count($wp_query->posts) > 0) {
    $offices = $wp_query->posts;
}

$keys = [];
foreach ($offices as $office) {
    $keys[] = get_post_meta($office->ID, '_office_id', true);
}

foreach ($records as $record) {
    $record_key = strtoupper(str_replace(' ', '',
        trim($record->location_id) . trim($record->business_unit)));

    if (isset($keys) & !empty($keys)) {
        if (in_array($record_key, $keys)) {
            echo $record_key . ' has a record in WordPress.<br/>';
        } else {
            echo '<b>' . $record_key . ' doesnt have a record in WordPress.</b><br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I'm currently getting with the above code which is working perfectly:

> MONTREALFHTOR has a record in WordPress.
>   MPLSFHUSA doesnt have a record in WordPress.
>   NEWYORKFHUSA has a record in WordPress.
>   ORANGECO.FHUSA doesnt have a record in WordPress.

But the above code will loop through all the $keys over 100+ times until it matches all the $record_key - Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

> ```
>  -- While loop over offices  
>  -- In the loop, for each office, get post meta location ID and business unit and put together as new key  
>  -- Loop through the offices one time, and build an array  
>  -- Use that array to loop through $records once to match the $record_key and $keys
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in your previous question - you won't notice if your script is slow with 100 elements. But still to optimize you can do this:

```
$keys = []; foreach ($offices as $office) {
    // Here you add result of `get_post_meta` as a KEY, not a VALUE, 
    // value is irrelevant and can be set to whatever you want, ie 1
    $keys[get_post_meta($office->ID, '_office_id', true)] = 1; 
}

foreach ($records as $record) {
    $record_key = strtoupper(str_replace(' ', '',
        trim($record->location_id) . trim($record->business_unit)));

    // here you check if KEY exists, it is faster then checking if VALUE exists
    if (!empty($keys[$record_key])) {
        echo $record_key . ' has a record in WordPress.<br/>';
    } else {
        echo '<b>' . $record_key . ' doesnt have a record in WordPress.</b><br/>';
    } 
}
```